# Compile libdwarf with VC++ Express 2010 failed to run Demo applications

Tags: windows, visual-c++, compilation, dwarf

I was able to compile `libdwarf` and `libelf` sucessfully with some warnings. I also successfully compiled the `simplereader` demo application but, failed to process the elf file. It always fail at:

```
void* _elf_read(Elf *elf, void *buffer, size_t off, size_t len)
```

in **input.c** under the `libelf` library.

I am using the latest 2012 `libdwarf` source code and the `libelf` from http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf

Any advise how I can fix it? If any who have done this port and is willing to share his/her work, will  be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem. The problem is not in with the Libelf but in the application simplereader. This application opens the file for read only whereas the libelf expects the file to be opened in binary. By adding "| _O_BINARY" everything goes well.